How to switch between cmake versions?
I have multiple project that has different CMake dependencies.
Unfortunately due to the complexity of the project, and not all CMake version's are 100% backward compatible.
Similar to python's virtual environment, is there a way to switch between CMake seamlessly?
I have installed past build from CMake's github artifact, and inserting the binary path in front of the PATH variable in the shell, so it will pick up the installed binaries.
export PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/:$PATH"


You'd just install multiple versions of cmake and call the right one when configuring your project.  Is your approach not working?

"Unfortunately due to the complexity of the project, not all CMake version's are 100% backward compatible." - CMake developers have great concerns about backward compatibility. It looks like you project does very tricky things...

@StephenNewell yes, it is exact how I made it work, I initially thought it was a the workaround, but looks like it is the right approach?

A workaround is to rename the cmake command of the specific version.
sudo mv /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake_3.29.1

After sourcing your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc you can call
cmake_3.29.1 --version

